# Is there an unstuck option for toilet doors?

Tags: borderlands-2

I got stuck in a toilet door and cant seem to get out.

Is there an unstuck option or will I have to quit and reload the game?

Comment: "I got stuck in a toilet door" *chuckle*  That should be the question title imo, "Help, I'm stuck in a toilet door and I can't get out!"

Comment: I had to do it. I couldn't help myself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nope, if you're completely stuck, there's no menu option or anything that will get you unstuck.

You have a few options:

- Try crouching, jumping, or crouch-jumping.  This can kind of unjam you if you're in a spot that's just a little bit out of the ordinary.
- Suicide, by throwing a grenade at a nearby wall, or firing some other explosive weapon, like a rocket launcher.  This costs some cash, but you'll probably lose less progress than saving and reloading.
- Get a friend to get close to you and duel, if you're playing multiplayer.  There's been a couple of times where starting a duel managed to unstick me from a weird spot, for whatever reason.

Finally, you can save and quit, which will reset the area and cause you to spawn at a save point.  Enemies in the area will probably respawn, and you may "fail" some quests (especially any with a timer involved, even if you haven't started the timer...) and have to start over.

Comment: I'm afraid I have to confirm this is true :( Getting stuck in Borderlands is very easy (because the game environment is too juicy and makes you try to jump everywhere), the only safe way out is (when possible) mind where you're going and how you're trying to go there!

Comment: I had tried the first options with out any luck, i ended up quiting and joining a friends game.

Answer (score 0):

Try jumping around, running & jumping etc, theres no easy way.

I've found that grenade jumping can sometimes help.  To do that, unequip your grenade mod, throw a grenade on the ground, and make sure you're in the air (jumping) when it explodes.